# Pass data from google maps to website

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, mysqli

Is it possible to have the google map that is on my website to pass data to a external source? For example the user clicks a restaurant and its passes the restaurant name to my website and stored in a MySQL database to be displayed later? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of "google map" do you have on your website? Is it a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map?  If so, then yes, it is possible.  What does your existing code look like?

Comment: I do not have that type of Google map. I will however update my website to that. Do you have a example or a tutorial I can use to get that functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener for click events (like on a marker) and use that to also execute your own code on the dom / AJAX calls / submit forms, etc. Stole a fiddle and modified for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h9cLd/ Click a marker the text at the bottom will change.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(r, 'click', function() { 
    //stuff
 };
```